# For para jQuery

Tags: jquery

Assim, eu possuo ao todo 4 divs que quero que sejam alteradas quando o mouse passa e quando o mouse sai dela. O efeito que queria fazer deu certo, mas queria diminuir o código para que seja mais fácil a manutenção, por isto estou aqui. Vou passar o código javascript e os dois blocos que estou tentando fazer este for. Também outra pergunta, este efeito não deixa muito pesado a aplicação para o usuário, ou deixa? Obrigado

JS

```
$('#bloco1').mouseenter(function (){
      $('.fraseBloco1').stop().fadeOut(0);
      $('.imgBloco1').stop().fadeOut(0);
      $('.conteudoBloco1').stop().fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $('#bloco1').mouseleave(function (){
      $('.conteudoBloco1').stop().fadeOut(0);
      $('.fraseBloco1').stop().fadeIn(1000);
      $('.imgBloco1').stop().fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="bloco1" id="bloco1">
                    <img class="imgBloco1" src="" />IMAGEM DO BLOCO
                    <p class="fraseBloco1">AQUI É TIPO UM TITULO</p>
                    <span class="conteudoBloco1" style="display: none;">DESCRICAO QUE APARECE QUANDO MOUSE ENTRA</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: É este o aspeto que tem agora? http://jsfiddle.net/oem6e6uw/

Comment: tipo isso http://jsfiddle.net/oem6e6uw/2/

Comment: Ok. É isto que procura? http://jsfiddle.net/oem6e6uw/3/

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Mas isto não terá problemas com o IE 7?

Comment: O IE7 é história. A Microsoft já deixou até de suportar oficialmente o IE8. Mas se quiser pode juntar `filter: alpha(opacity=0);` mas eu não o faria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fica uma sugestão com CSS somente:

```
.bloco1 > * {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.bloco1:hover > p, .bloco1:hover > img {
    opacity: 0;
}
.bloco1:hover > .conteudoBloco1 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Pode ainda ter de juntar `position: relative;` ao elemento `.bloco1`.

Esta é a melhor maneira do ponto de vista de simplicidade de código e performance.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/oem6e6uw/3/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="blocos" id="bloco1">
    <img class="imgBloco1 item-bloco" src="" />IMAGEM DO BLOCO
    <p class="fraseBloco1 item-bloco">AQUI É TIPO UM TITULO</p>
    <span class="conteudoBloco1 desc-bloco">DESCRICAO QUE APARECE QUANDO MOUSE ENTRA</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.blocos').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.item-bloco').stop().fadeOut(0);
        $(this).find('.desc-bloco').stop().fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('.desc-bloco').stop().fadeOut(0);
        $(this).find('.item-bloco').stop().fadeIn(1000);
    }
);
```

Comment: É. Fica a dica de uma solução só com CSS, se a posição dos elementos puder ser fixada: http://jsfiddle.net/b06jy67a/

Comment: Não deu certo, pois o que vai aparecer será no lugar do que sai, também são no caso 4 blocos com o mesmo requesito

Comment: Por isso eu falei em fixar as posições. Basicamente, é o que o Sergio fez na resposta dele.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma mais limpa de fazer, sem tantas classes e ids:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bloco">
    <img class="imgBloco" src="" />
    <p class="fraseBloco">AQUI É TIPO UM TITULO</p>
    <span class="conteudoBloco" style="display: none;">DESCRICAO QUE APARECE QUANDO MOUSE ENTRA</span>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.bloco').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.imgBloco, .fraseBloco').stop().hide();
    $(this).children('.conteudoBloco').stop().fadeIn(1000);
}, function () {
    $(this).children('.imgBloco, .fraseBloco').stop().fadeIn(1000);
    $(this).children('.conteudoBloco').stop().hide();
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/2tuvh0xw/).